# Icon for iWeb published site?

Tags: mac, icon, graphics, websites, iweb

How can I use a *favicon* for my website that is published using iWeb?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, there appears to be no way to create a favicon via the gui elements of iWeb. However, you are able to pretty simply add the html to the published version of your site.

I recommend following [this guide from All About iWeb](http://allaboutiweb.com/index.php/2008/08/add-favicon-to-iweb-site/). It walks you through how to first create the favicon using one of a variety of free online tools and then informs you where it needs be stored in your site's structure as well as the necessary html you need to add to your pages.

Answer (score 1):

Can you define what you mean by a "personal icon"?

Are you referring to the image shown next to the URL in the address bar? That's called a [*favicon*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon).

Or do you mean an image on the web page itself that represents you/your site, such as [the apple](http://www.apple.com) on the left-hand side of the menubar at the top of `apple.com`? That can be called any number of things (header graphic, home button, etc.), but it's just a normal graphic in png, jpg, or gif format.

Answer (score 1):

[This article](http://www.macworld.com/article/143385/2009/11/favicon.html) should be just the thing.

Comment: Yes, *if* he happens to have Photoshop lying around. Oh, and it doesn't say what to do in iWeb with it when he's done, either.

Comment: *The article* says to use Ps, but it doesn't take much imagination to see that use can use GIMP (free), and many other editors. And, I assume that OP has some experience with inserting code snippets. If so, he's good to go.

Comment: *I assume that OP has some experience with inserting code snippets* —actually, given that iWeb doesn't let you insert code snippets, it's not a terribly good assumption to make (and yes, iWeb is retarded, but that's another issue entirely).

Comment: TextEdit does. So does Smultron (also free). To use TextEdit to edit Web code: File-> Open. Check the Ignore Rich Text Commands box at the bottom, and you've got your web code. The article shows exactly what and where to paste in.

Comment: And so does [TextWrangler](http://www.barebones.com/products/textwrangler/) (also free). But the article does *not* mention that the next time he opens the page with iWeb, he'll lose those text edits—kinda important, imo. Maybe it's just me, but I think that a novice would find that terribly confusing.